# Reduce Processing Time of accessing database

Tags: iphone, optimization, time

I'm making an app which requires a remote database connection. I want the values in picker from database, but when I click on button to invoke picker it takes some time to fetch the values and displaying. Is there any way to do it fast?

and also is there any way to reduce the time of transition between 2 views?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

If data is not frequently changes then try to load all the data at the starting point of application.And while loading picker control just show that data.

Write your data fetching code in applicationDidFinishLaunching.

For view transition if you are writing custom code for view transiotion then try to set [UIView setAnimationDuration:ANIMATION_TIME]; in your code.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Jim.

Comment: thanx Jim, but i have to show data in picker according to some conditions filled in the textfields. is there any way in that case?

for view transition the above line doesn't help me. 
my problem is: I fill some textfields then click a button which then connects the database and search some records then finally show it on the next view.

Thanx.